# Obtener permisos totales para mover archivos a la tarjeta externa: microSD

Tags: java, android

Llevo unos meses en el desarrollo de una app, y me falta poder mover archivos a la externa a partir de **Lollipop** en adelante (Android M, etc). Con la siguiente línea de código se le muestra al usuario una ventana para Mostrar SD, marcar y dar en Seleccionar, pero: **¿Cómo obtengo permisos para mover a la microSD?**

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), 42);
```

He mirado muchas webs que indican que les funciona, o funcionaba en **Lollipop** pero no veo resultados. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Estaba viendo este link, por si puede servir:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow

> No veo que funcione: sigo sin poder mover archivos a la externa.

Comment: Hola Sergio, bienvenido a [es.so]. El idioma oficial del sitio es el español. Has de traducir la pregunta o será cerrada. Tambien puedes borrarla y hacerla en [so]. Un saludo

Comment: Al que ha votado negativo recuerda: [Ser paciente con los votos cuando una pregunta está en inglés](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1092/15855)

Comment: en principio los permisos necesarios creo que son `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` y `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`.De todas maneras creo recordar que a partir de KItKat, las aplicaciones de terceros no pueden escribir en la SD

Comment: Sí, gracias, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE y READ... ya están añadidos a Manifest. Esto servía cuando Android kk. Ahora únicamente sirve para trabajar con la memoria interna (que no es poco) y aparece como un permiso en Almacén (Ajustes de la app). Conozco aplicaciones que te crean una carpeta en cualquier parte de la microSD e incluso mueven archivos sin problemas. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Es cierto que Google restringió la escritura a la microSD, pero el desarrollador, con la solicitud de permisos adecuada, y el código correcto una vez aceptados dichos permisos (Seleccionar microSD), ya puede escribir en la externa.

Answer (score 0):

Hola este enfoque es correcto, aunque solo lo he utilizado para eliminar archivos de la sd no para escribir, pero supongo que debe funcionar.

Lo que debes hacer es trabajar a partir del uri que se te devuelve, al lanzar startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), 42);
te muestra el sitema de archivos de tu android, tienes que seleccionar la carpeta en la que deseas escribir, despues en una funcion onActivityResult asignar permisos "temporales" al uri devuelto algo asi:

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String treeUri = null;
                if (data != null){
//treeUri es un string 
                    treeUri = data.getDataString();
                }
                Log.d("Regresa", "onActivityResult: "+treeUri);
                if (treeUri != null ) {
//se convierte en uri
                    UriSD= Uri.parse(treeUri);
                    Log.d("ResultFinal: "," --"+treeUri+"--"+UriSD);
                    content=getContentResolver();
//Se asignan los permisos al uri
             content.takePersistableUriPermission(UriSD,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      
    //Ahora debes crear un DocumentFile a partir de este uri
    
     DocumentFile doc=DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getApplicationContext(),UriSD);
 //Ya solo creas tu archivo perro en vez de usar File utilizas DocumentFile
```

DocumentFile file=new DocumentFile(getAplicationContext(),UriSD+"tu archivo"
}

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score -1):

Me parece que lo que deseas es habilitar la opción para mover tu app a la Sdcard, para esto tienes que habilitar la opción dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

```
<manifest 
...
...
android:installLocation="auto">
```

Esto habilitara poder mover tu aplicación a la SDcard.

Comment: Ante todo muchas gracias por responder y aportar. Si con la opción de instalar mi app en la externa me permite también guardar archivos en la externa, lo probaré. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo he probado y no veo que me permita instalarlo en la SDcard. <manifest ... <aplication ... android:label="Nom_app" android:installLocation="auto" ... android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> <activity .......... etc. Quizás no lo haya puesto bien.

Comment: Lo que agregue es para poder realizarlo **desde los settings de la aplicación.**

Comment: Sí: he revisado en Settings y no he visto que esté habilitada la opción de mover la instalación a la SdCard.